# CSS: Won't center div with max-width

Tags: css, html, center

I've got the following page structure:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="content">
        <table>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the outher div `main-container` to have `max-width: 800px;` and the inner div to be wrapped around a table and to have the same with as the table. Also `<div class="content">` should be centered inside his parent div - `main-container`. What am I doing wrong here? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GMNf/8/)

**Working example:** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GMNf/13/)

Comment: just write the .main-container { text-align: center; } beacuss a inline block element behive middle between inline and block.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you need the `.content` to be *inline-block*, just set the container `text-align: center` and the content `text-align: left`. You won't be able to center *inline-block* elements using `margin: auto`.

Comment: what if I have some text inside the .content that I don't want to be centered - I just want to center the whole div, without affecting the content inside this div

Comment: Set the content's text align to left

Answer (score 81):

I had a similar issue. Setting

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

on the inner div worked for me.

Comment: or even on the save div

Comment: Amazing! Been trying tons of suggestions and yours was the only one that really worked.  Sometimes I really wish there was a backward-bounty option on SO. ;)

Comment: Still the best easiest answer in Oct 2021, thanks Gideon!

Answer (score 16):

I tried this and it worked

```
.element-container{
   width:100%;
   max-width: 700px;
   margin: 0px auto;
}
.element{
   width: 80%;
   max-width: 700px;
   height: auto;
   margin-left: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `display: flex`, because it reduces much CSS code as you can see below;

```
.main-container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jeos3q15)**

Answer (score 3):

You could just change display to `table`.
http://jsfiddle.net/4GMNf/14/

#### CSS

```
.main-container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
.content {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: gray;
    display: table;
}

table 
{
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display: inline-block;` from `.content` CSS class

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4GMNf/9/)

Comment: As I said - the inner div should be with the same width as the table. I'm using `dispaly: inline-block` to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/4GMNf/10/

CSS

```
.main-container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
.content {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: gray;
}
table {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: The inner div's width should depend on the table's width. I'm using `dispaly: inline-block` to achieve this. Your answer is not working here.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually,** an inline-block element not taken width parent it still contents width, Because a inline-block element behive the middle between block and non-block or inline. So, When you talk this element is inline-block then talk the parent text-align center.

**Here the code:**

**Ans-1:**

```css
.main-container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
.content {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}

table 
{
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="content">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                     <h1>Name</h1>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <input type="text" Text="" id="txt">
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ans 2:**

```css
.main-container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
.content {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: gray;
}

table 
{
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="content">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                     <h1>Name</h1>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <input type="text" Text="" id="txt">
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```